# Batch output parsing

Tags: parsing, batch-file, cmd

I have the following command and output:

```
fastboot get
< waiting for device >
...
(bootloader) ---------------------------------------------------------
(bootloader) Device-ID
(bootloader) 2FC9A68923FD175AA6E13657181CA6AB
(bootloader) 4AE438F12376AFA85D0E3467AE83A752
(bootloader) ---------------------------------------------------------
OKAY [  0.020s]
finished. total time: 0.020s
```

How can I get the serial as: `2FC9A68923FD175AA6E13657181CA6AB4AE438F12376AFA85D0E3467AE83A752`

also please explain the solution as much as possible

Comment: Are there any other instances of `Device-ID` anywhere else in the output?

Comment: No that's all the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: Get the line containing the string "Device-ID"
:: Use findstr to show the line number, then take everything left of the colon
:: This assumes that the script is in the same directory as your output data and the data is in data.txt
for /F "tokens=1 delims=:" %%A in ('findstr /C:"Device-ID" /N data.txt') do set id_line=%%A

:: For the first id_line lines of data.txt, store that value in a dummy variable
:: Store the line after that in id_part[1], and the line after that in id_part[2]
(
    for /L %%A in (1,1,!id_line!) do (
        set /p skip_line=
    )
    set /p id_part[1]=
    set /p id_part[2]=
)<data.txt


:: For if_part[1] and then id_part[2],
:: Split the value of the variable on the space between (bootloader) and the value
:: Store the right side of the value in the id_part variable
for /L %%A in (1,1,2) do (
    for /F "tokens=2" %%B in ("!id_part[%%A]!") do set id_part[%%A]=%%B
)

:: Join the two parts of the ID together
set serial=!id_part[1]!!id_part[2]!

:: Display the ID
echo !serial!
pause
```